# INVALID_ARGUMENT: transpose expects a vector of size 0 (when GPU units are more than 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using a pre-trained model to train an image classifier. Below Code is running fine on CPU and single unit GPU (i.e. when #GPU=1)

```
class Metrics(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_tf_data, val_tf_data, CLASSES, logs={}, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.keras_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Mean("val_f1_after_epoch")
        self.train_tf_data = train_tf_data
        self.val_tf_data = val_tf_data
        # self.model = model
        self.CLASSES = CLASSES

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # self.keras_metric.reset_state()
        # for train data
        self.train_reports = test_model(model=self.model, data=self.train_tf_data, CLASSES=self.CLASSES)
        self.train_f1_after_epoch = self.train_reports['f1_score']
        self.train_recall_after_epoch = self.train_reports['recall']
        self.train_prec_after_epoch = self.train_reports['precision']

        # for val data
        self.val_reports = test_model(model=self.model, data=self.val_tf_data, CLASSES=self.CLASSES)
        self.val_f1_after_epoch = self.val_reports['f1_score']
        self.val_recall_after_epoch = self.val_reports['recall']
        self.val_prec_after_epoch = self.val_reports['precision']

        # saving train results to log dir
        logs["f1_after_epoch"]=self.train_f1_after_epoch
        logs['precision_after_epoch'] = self.train_prec_after_epoch
        logs['recall_after_epoch'] = self.train_recall_after_epoch
        
        # saving val results to log dir
        logs['val_f1_after_epoch'] = self.val_f1_after_epoch
        logs['val_precision_after_epoch'] = self.val_prec_after_epoch
        logs['val_recall_after_epoch'] = self.val_recall_after_epoch
        # self.keras_metric.update_state(self.val_f1_after_epoch)

        print('reports_after_epoch', self.train_reports)
        print('val_reports_after_epoch', self.val_reports)
        



with strategy.scope():
    pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
                                                    weights='imagenet',
                                                    include_top=False,
                                                    input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, IMG_CHANNELS])
    pretrained_model.trainable = True #fine tuning
    q_aware_pretrained_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(pretrained_model,
                                                          clone_function=apply_quantization_to_dense,)
    base_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                            tf.keras.layers.Lambda(# Convert image from int[0, 255] to the format expect by this base_model
                            lambda data:tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(
                                tf.cast(data, tf.float32)), input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]),
                            q_aware_pretrained_model,
                            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()])
    base_model.layers[1]._name = 'custom_mnet_trainable'
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, name='object_dense',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.1)))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center = False))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name='relu_dense_64'))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5, name='dropout_dense_64'))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, name='object_dense_2',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.1)))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center = False))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name='relu_dense_32'))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4, name='dropout_dense_32'))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, name='object_dense_16', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.1)))
    base_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(CLASS_NAMES), activation='softmax', name='object_prob'))
    m1 = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
    m3 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()

    m4 = Metrics(train_tf_data=train_data, val_tf_data=test_data, CLASSES=CLASS_NAMES)


    optimizers = [
        tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr * .001 , weight_decay=wd),
        tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr, weight_decay=wd)
            ]

    optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], base_model.layers[0]), (optimizers[1], base_model.layers[1:])]

    optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)

    annotated_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(
        base_model,
        clone_function=apply_quantization_to_dense,
    )


    model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply(annotated_model)
    model.compile(
        optimizer= optimizer, loss=tfa.losses.SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO),
        metrics=[m1, m2, m3],
        )

tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_logdir)

checkpoint_name = os.getcwd() + os.sep + CUSTOM_MODEL_PATH + os.sep + "training_chkpts/cp-{epoch:04d}-{val_f1_after_epoch:.2f}.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir_path  = os.getcwd() + os.sep + CUSTOM_MODEL_PATH + os.sep+ "training_chkpts"
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_name, 
                                                    monitor = 'val_f1_after_epoch',
                                                    save_best_only=True,
                                                    save_weights_only=True,
                                                    mode='max',
                                                    save_freq='epoch',
                                                    verbose=1)

checkpoint_cb._supports_tf_logs = False
current_dir = os.getcwd()
history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, 
                    epochs=N_EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=[m4, checkpoint_cb, tensorboard_cb])
```

**But If I use a system when the number of GPU > 1 then it is throwing the below error.**

Epoch 1/2
6/Unknown - 44s 150ms/step - loss: 19.2255 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0625 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - precision: 0.0000e+00

/bwz_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:1410: CustomMaskWarning: Custom mask layers require a config and must override get_config. When loading, the custom mask layer must be passed to the custom_objects argument.
layer_config = serialize_layer_fn(layer)
288/Unknown - 84s 141ms/step - loss: 13.7873 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1788 - recall: 0.0080 - precision: 0.77082021-12-30 15:08:31.404434: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] **OP_REQUIRES failed at transpose_op.cc:142 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/ssd/custom_mnet_v2.py", line 536, in 
history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data,
File "bwz_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/bwz_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 58, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 3 root error(s) found.

(0) **INVALID_ARGUMENT:  transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4**
[[{{node gradient_tape/replica_1/sequential/custom_mnet_trainable/Conv1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
[[div_no_nan_3/ReadVariableOp/_558]]

(1) **INVALID_ARGUMENT:  transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4**
[[{{node gradient_tape/replica_1/sequential/custom_mnet_trainable/Conv1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
[[assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_4049/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_4/_546]]

**(2) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4**
[[{{node gradient_tape/replica_1/sequential/custom_mnet_trainable/Conv1/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_1079980]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function

Few things that I have already tested

1. Tried out different metrics (categorical_accuracy) to check whether the issue is realted to the custom monitoring metrics or not.
2. Run the code in CPU and single GPU enviroment and it is working perfectly fine

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n9MmaLKZORa0vQvluQcY3t-VuX-yiSxf?usp=sharing) is the link to the Google Colab Notebook to reproduce the error(please set #GPU>1)

Comment: you should specify layer shapes for easier debugging. Importantly, on lambda layer, write out output shape explicitli: ouput_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]. Batching with tf data for images can cause issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27245 so it is best to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, including output_shape in the lambda layer. Getting the same error information

Comment: Can you do a model.summary()?

Answer (score 3):

I'm 70% confident this is caused by your lambda layer. I *think* that when you run multi-GPU, your model needs to be serializable so that it can be placed on each GPU. I think lambda layers cannot be serialized.

See this note:

```
WARNING: tf.keras.layers.Lambda layers have (de)serialization limitations!
```

here
https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/.

Trying rewriting your lambda layers as a real custom layer that supports serialization, ie it implements get_config(). So instead of

```
lambda data:tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(
                                tf.cast(data, tf.float32)),
```

write a proper custom layer as

```
class Prep(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  
  def get_config(self):
    return super().get_config()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(
                                tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32))
```

then add that new Prep layer into your sequential model. LMK if that works. If not I'll delete this response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please provide a way to include this in the sequential API. I am trying this by calling Prep in the above code inside tf.keras.layers.Layer(Prep()) but it is throwing an error.

Also if I directly call Prep() without tf.keras.layers.Layer it is throwing an error saying ValueError: `model` must be a built model. been built yet. Please call `model.build(input_shape)` before quantizing your model.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the integration? As mentioned I have tried with the above code but it is giving me an error mentioned in my first comment above

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I did have a typo - input instead of inputs - which I've fixed.

Comment: If I am using Prep inside tf.keras.layers.Lambda  with Lambda i.e. tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Lambda(Prep()), q_aware_pretrained_model......]) then I am getting ValueError: `model` must be a built model. been built yet. Please call `model.build(input_shape)` before quantizing your model. 
Aslso using Prep inside tf.keras.Sequential without tf.keras.layers.Lambda i.e. tf.keras.Sequential([Prep(), q_aware_quantized_model,.......]) I am getting the same error. Can you please elaborate your answer by mentioning how to use this in the current code shown code ?

Comment: Which line of code triggers the stack trace? Fit? Have you tried calling model.build() on the shape of the training data? If it's a tf.data.Datset, you may need data.element_spec.shape, or if it's a tensor/numpy array, you may be able to use data.shape or tf.shape(data).

Comment: Please visit this link (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n9MmaLKZORa0vQvluQcY3t-VuX-yiSxf?usp=sharing) to have a clear view of the error. If you see, the code in cell number 12 is working fine but the code in cell number 14 is not working and throwing an error. (Cell number 14 included the suggestion provided by you)

Comment: Your notebook requires access to your google drive... sorry I can't help more here.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. You don't need access to my Gdrive. There is a link to data which you can download and upload to your own Gdrive. . Link is there in the collab. This code seems to fail at my end so my apology here for not accepting it as a solution.